# SWIG C++ to {Dart/Flutter; and SWIFT} binding

Tags: c++, flutter, dart, swig

I am looking for a nice way to have a C++ library exposed to Dart/Flutter and SWIFT (obviously targetting mobile here).

'been around SWIG for a long time, but can't find anything for new languages like Dart/Flutter & SFWIT (targetting Android/IOS dev).

We already have the Python and Java binding on SWIG, would be great to get those 2.

If SWIG can't do the trick, is there other wrappers of the like more appropriate?

Comment: Any luck? Wondering about same approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight way to export C++ library to Dart/Flutter

1. Take advantage of [dart:ffi](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/c-interop) (with [package:ffi](https://pub.dev/packages/ffi) &
   [package:ffigen](https://pub.dev/packages/ffigen)), to interact with [C wrapper of C++](https://caiorss.github.io/C-Cpp-Notes/CwrapperToQtLibrary.html)
2. Use Fluttter plugin to bridge call from MethodChannel
   to C++ library

Answer (score 0):

Alternative (not tested!!!) use emscripten aka `C++` -> `asm.js` then load it in flutter using the `EmscriptenModule`.

ref: https://pub.dev/documentation/web_ffi/latest/web_ffi_modules/EmscriptenModule-class.html

Also look at https://github.com/rwl/emscripten in the same mood.